# Inserting muliple rows in SQL with SubQuery

Tags: sql, t-sql

Suppose I have 2 tables.

```
Roles                                  Rights

Id  | Name                        Id | Type | Name
--------------------             -----------------

100 | 1001_MgmtAdmin             999 | User | Rename
200 | 2001_MgmtAdmin
300 | 3001_MgmtAdmin
```

and I would like to create following entries within existing table ( i.e. RolesRightsMapping )

```
RolesRightsMapping

Id | RoleId | RightsId
----------------------

900 |  100   | 999
800 |  200   | 999
1000|  300   | 999
```

I am using SQL Sub Query as I don't see any other option but It says , 'Sub Query returns more than one record which cannot be used when it is used as an expression or contains operators >, <=, >='

```
INSERT INTO RolesRightsMapping
VALUES ( SELECT Id FROM Roles.Id WHERE Name Like 'MgmtAdmin', SELECT Id FROM Rights WHERE Name = 'Rename' and Type = 'User' )
```

I even hold the result of SubQuery into an array and then inserted the results back using SELECT statement but got the same error.

Any help how it is possible to have the results shown in the above table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 INSERT INTO RolesRightsMapping(RoleId,RightsId)
      SELECT roles.id,rights.id from Roles,rights 
    where INITCAP(Roles.Name) LIKE 'MgmtAdmin' 
AND rights.Name = 'Rename' AND rights.Type = 'User';
```

Comment: apart from INITCAP, everything was fine. Thanks. It worked as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO RolesRightsMapping (RoleId, RightsId)
    SELECT r.Id, ri.id
    FROM Roles r CROSS JOIN
         Rights ri
    WHERE r.Name Like 'MgmtAdmin' AND
          ri.Name = 'Rename' AND ri.Type = 'User'
```

Comment: @Usman . . . Either would work.  The conditions are independent for each table but they can go in an `on` clause as well.